# Named Arguments in PHP

Tags: c#, php, asp.net

In C#, there is a new feature coming with 4.0 called Named Arguments and get along well with Optional Parameters.

```
private static void writeSomething(int a = 1, int b = 2){
   // do something here;
}

static void Main()
{
   writeSomething(b:3); // works pretty well 
}
```

I was using this option to get some settings value from users.

In PHP, I cannot find anything similar except for the optional parameters but I am accepting doing `$.fn.extend` (jQuery) kind of function :

```
function settings($options)
{
   $defaults = array("name"=>"something","lastname"=>"else");
   $settings = array_merge($defaults,$options);
}

settigs(array("lastname"=>"John");
```

I am wondering what kind of solutions you are using or you would use for the same situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you found out, named arguments don't exist in PHP.

But one possible solution would be to use one array as unique parameter -- as array items can be named :

```
my_function(array(
    'my_param' => 10, 
    'other_param' => 'hello, world!', 
));
```

And, in your function, you'd read data from that unique array parameter :

```
function my_function(array $params) {

    // test if $params['my_param'] is set ; and use it if it is
    // test if $params['other_param'] is set ; and use it if it is
    // test if $params['yet_another_param'] is set ; and use it if it is
    // ...

}
```

Still, there is one major inconvenient with this idea : looking at your function's definition, people will have no idea what parameters it expects / they can pass.

They will have to go read the documentation each time they want to call your function -- which is not something one loves to do, is it ?

Additionnal note : IDEs won't be able to provide hints either ; and phpdoc will be broken too...

Comment: Eclipse works fine with the PHPdoc user defined. They might need to check which parameters they need to send but at least they don't have to follow an order and don't need to pass everything but I know it ain't elegant as much as the C# way of accomplishing same thing.

Comment: Eclipse will suggest which names you can use for keys of the array ?

Comment: No but you can write it down on the doc description which keys accepted so once users move mouse over the `function` he/she will see the documentation pops up. Since it dynamic structure it is hard for IDEs to offer auto-completion completely yet Eclipse is pretty fine doing this.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought ; not quite a great solution :-(

Answer (score 1):

You can get around that by having an array such as `$array= array('arg1'=>'value1');`
And then let the function accept the array such as `function dostuff($stuff);`
Then, you can check arguments using `if(isset($stuff['arg1')){//do something.}` inside the function itself

It's just a work-around but maybe it could help

Comment: What about the default values. I like to use default values for the variables not assigned.

Comment: When using arrays to provide data, you are in total control how to use arrays.

Comment: To have default values, the idea is in the function, to use `if(isset($stuff['arg1')){
   //do something, a value is set
} else {
   //do something, a value isn't set. Use a default value here
}`

Answer (score 1):

You can fake C++-style optional arguments (i.e. all optional arguments are at the end) by checking for set variables:

```
function foo($a, $b)
{
  $x = isset($a) ? $a : 3;
  $y = isset($b) ? $b : 4;
  print("X = $x, Y = $y\n");
}

@foo(8);
@foo();
```

It'll trigger a warning, which I'm suppressing with `@`. Not the most elegant solution, but syntactically close to what you wanted.

---

**Edit.** That was a silly idea. Use variadic arguments instead:

```
// faking foo($x = 3, $y = 3)
function foo()
{
  $args = func_get_args();
  $x = isset($args[0]) ? $args[0] : 3;
  $y = isset($args[1]) ? $args[1] : 3;
  print("X = $x, Y = $y\n");
}

foo(12,14);
foo(8);
foo();
```

Comment: Still position matters here. I cannot pass value to `$b` without passing a value for `$a`. Correct if I misunderstood.

Comment: That's true, you cannot have an omitted argument _before_ an explicit argument this way.

Comment: But this is a very vague technique. Trusting too much to the function consumer?

Comment: Well... document your functions correctly! Alternatively use the more verbose array-based arguments that others have suggested, that'll allow you to handle specific errors.