# can php functions have keyword arguments? (like python)

Tags: php, function, arguments

I want to do this:

```
function they_said($alice = "", $bob = "", $charlie = "") {
    echo "Alice said '$alice'";
    echo "Bob said '$bob'";
    echo "Charlie said '$charlie'";
}

they_said($charlie => "Where are the cookies!?");
```

That way I can ignore passing the first 2 arguments and simply pass the one I want.

Comment: and [Named Arguments in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6800379)

Comment: I agree that this question is a duplicate of the others. (I didn't find them because they used different words to describe the problem than I did.)

Comment: Although this question is IMO better formulated than the one it duplicates.

Comment: I know its helpful to pass named argument like in Python...In php you can do it like $my_param = true; my_function($my_param);

Comment: I shared a Q/A as a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56415163

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, but you can pass an array:

```
function they_said($persons)
{
  foreach ($persons as $person => $text)
  {
    echo "$person said '$text'";
  }
}
they_said( array('charlie' => 'Where are the cookies!?') );
```