# PHP mkdir() failing to work

Tags: php, path, directory, mkdir

Here's my code; I've renamed the directories, obviously. ;)

```
$thepath = "/var/www/vhosts/sub.domain.co.uk/web/apps/storage/".$userclient."/evidence/".$scid."/".$doctype."/";
$testdir = is_dir($thepath); 
if ($testdir == false) {
    mkdir($thepath, 0777);
}
```

In this case, the following variables apply;

```
$userclient = '000';
$scid       = '9263';
$doctype    = 'Insurance Policy';
```

So, the path should be;

```
/var/www/vhosts/sub.domain.co.uk/web/apps/storage/000/evidence/9263/Insurance Policy/
```

I know this works, EVERYWHERE else in my code, I have other applications using an almost identical setup. But the one above, appears to be tripping up on /evidence/ - it sets the permissions to 755, but will then create the directories per time I run the code, if I set evidence to 777 (Octal).

I get the following error message using;

```
if (!@mkdir($thepath)) {
    $error = error_get_last();
    echo $error['message'];
}
mkdir(): No such file or directory
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have to finish this application by Thursday - and this file upload part is the last bit!

Thank you!

Comment: Chances are its falling over on the space....

Comment: There's no chance of that, the paths in other areas of code operate perfectly, and work perfectly - which also have spaces in (URL readbacks replace spaces with %20 - which is fine ^^)

Comment: But your PHP code doesnt turn the space to %20.. I would personally backslash escape the space.

Comment: Thanks for the comments BugFinder, I have it working now based on setting recursive. I've used spaces in directories for years and it's always worked fine, so i've never bothered with extra bits ;P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP can't find directory in which you want to create other directory.

You need to set `$recursive` param as true:

```
mkdir($thepath, 0777, true);
```

Comment: But the code works perfectly else where, it creates the directories no problem, one directory short. Where '000/evidence/9263/Insurance Policy/' would be, elsewhere it creates '000/subimages/9263/picture.jpg' no problem. :/

Comment: @Daniil, while the suggestion to set recursive to true is valid, the code you propose sets local variable `$recursive` to true and passes it as a mode.

Comment: Didn't work with php for a while. How is it possible to set keyword argument in php?

Comment: Is it even possible? I think it's just the third parameter (see my answer). But it doesn't matter, you've got your answer accepted, anyway ;)

Comment: @Michael Krelin - hacker, looks like this is really not possible (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704339/can-php-functions-have-keyword-arguments-like-python). Sorry, fixed my answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to try `mkdir($path,$mode,true)` to create missing links as well?

Comment: What's '$mode, true' going to do? D:

Comment: Have you considered reading documentation for php `mkdir` function?

Comment: I have yes, missread my statement, I mean - how will it make it any different? The code works fine everywhere else, but falls over here with one extra directory in depth. :/

Comment: Well, if you create directory `/a/b/c` where `/a/b` exists, it should work just fine. If you only have `/a` and want to create `/a/b/c` you need to create missing directory as well and this is what recursive is for.

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean. I've tried both suggestions and both make it work, so thank you very much guys. :)