# Equivalent of python's **kwargs in php

Tags: php, python

Is there a good way to pass an arbitrary number of named arguments to functions in php (something like `**kwargs` in python).  `func_get_args()` in php doesn't seem to do it, as it just produces arguments in a specified order, which is what I'm trying to move away from with some legacy php code.  Are `ReflectionFunction` and `ReflectionParameter` worth looking into?  I thought about just passing an array or object as the sole argument and then inspecting them, but thought there must be a better way.

Comment: As far as I know, php does not even support keyword arguments?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800379/named-arguments-in-php , and others asking about name arguments,  alas they don't seem to exist.  So path of least resistance is probably array/assoc array/hash with all your arguments in there, and just pick out the ones you want/need, et...